# Column Date(INDEX?) pandas can not be set as y in matplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

my simple code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame('data')

print(type(df))
print(df.columns)
print(df.head())
```

output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index(['Value'], dtype='object')
             Value
Date              
2010-03-31  965.95
2010-04-01  974.99
2010-04-06  963.82
2010-04-07  968.23
2010-04-08  972.51
```

my question is, how can i access Date column? I would like to use it for matplot Y axis:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.scatter(x, y = df['Date']))
```

The problem is, I can't access it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

plt.scatter(df['Value'],df.index)
```

[image]